# PHP E-Mail Form w/Options

Tags: php

I need to include the first code (which calls the e-mail from a WordPress options panel) in the second code where it says email@mail.com.  I tried to include " around the code, but it doesn't seem to work.  I also tried to strip slashes, but to no avail.

How I call the e-mail

```
<?php echo get_option('to_email'); ?>
```

The relevant part of my contact form:

```
    if(!isset($hasError)) {

        $emailTo = 'email@mail.com';
        $subject = 'Contact Form Submission from '.$name;
        $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
        $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: Could you explain why you can't use get_option inside your second script. Are these scripts on different servers or something and you are trying to include the first one over http to the second one?

Answer (score 0):

```
$emailTo = get_option('to_email');
```

You have to make sure the right files are included (wordpress config files).